# Take in file as prop

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that renders sentences but it also translates the sentences and can insert tags inside of the resulting element. It has this general structure:

```
import React from 'react';
import langFile from 'file_with_sentences.lang';
import TranslateAndInsert from 'translator';

class SentenceRenderer extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let sentenceToTranslate = langFile.sentence;
        let tagToInsert = <a>See more</a>;
        return (
            <p>
                {TranslateAndInsert(sentenceToTranslate, tagToInsert)}
            </p>
        )
    }
}

export default SentenceRenderer
```

So for example, `sentenceToTranslate` could be a sentence with a placeholder that gets replaced by the `tagToInsert`. Something like `"I am a sentence to translate looks at me {$0}"` and `{$0}` would get replaced by the `<a>See more</a>`.

I want to be able to generalize this component so that instead of hardcoding a `langFile` to extract the sentence from, it would instead take in a file from which to extract the sentence from. Can you pass in a file as a prop? Could this be done with a higher order component?

Comment: Not sure about the use case, would it make sense to read the file from a parent comp, and pass the content of the file down?

Comment: *it would instead take in a file from which to extract the sentence from* - the problem is how this fits your environment. Are there multiple files? How are they supposed to be loaded? When using modules, you need to make sure that Webpack will bundle translation files, so file names need to be hard-coded at some point. If you intend to load them dynamically, they need to be JSON files that are loaded with AJAX. I'd suggest to make up your mind, the answer depends on how you expect this to be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the dynamic import. You can pass in the file path down as a prop. Then do the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { path } = this.props;
    import(`${path}`)
      .then(module => this.setState({ module: module.default }))
  }
```

That should allow you have access to the state, then apply your utility functions around it.